# jQuery datepicker, onSelect won't work

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onselect

I can't get `onSelect` working on my jQuery `datepicker`.

Heres my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.date-pick').datePicker( {
        onSelect: function(date) {
            alert(date)
        },
        selectWeek: true,
        inline: true,
        startDate: '01/01/2000',
        firstDay: 1,
    });
});
</script>
```

It's like it doesn't register the `onSelect` function.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

No comma after the last property.

Semicolon after alert(date);

Case on datepicker (not datePicker)

Check your other uppercase / lowercase for the properties.

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-pick').datepicker( {
        onSelect: function(date) {
            alert(date);
        },
        selectWeek: true,
        inline: true,
        startDate: '01/01/2000',
        firstDay: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: In js you can ommit the semicolon if that's the end of the line and, like in many languages, you can put a comma after the last property.

Answer (score 15):

datePicker's onSelect equivalent is the dateSelected event.

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-pick').datePicker( {
        selectWeek: true,
        inline: true,
        startDate: '01/01/2000',
        firstDay: 1,
    }).bind('dateSelected', function(e, selectedDate, $td) {
        alert(selectedDate);
    });
});
```

[This page](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerKarmasAgent.html) has a good example showing the dateSelected event and other events being bound.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
                    autoclose : true,
                    todayHighlight : true,
                    clearBtn: true,
                    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', 
                    onSelect: function(value, date) { 
                         alert(123);
                    },
                    todayBtn: "linked",
                    startView: 0, maxViewMode: 0,minViewMode:0

                    }).on('changeDate',function(ev){
                    //this is right events ，trust me
                    }
});
```

Comment: i guess this is for bootstrap datepicker, nor jquery datepicker

Comment: changeDate does not trigger for me. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 5):

The function `datepicker` is case sensitive and all lowercase. The following however works fine for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.date-pick').datepicker( {
    onSelect: function(date) {
        alert(date);
    },
    selectWeek: true,
    inline: true,
    startDate: '01/01/2000',
    firstDay: 1
  });
});
```

Comment: "Error: Object doesn't support this property or method" on line 14, which is: $('.date-pick').datepicker( {

Comment: See comment above about which 'date picker' you are using - my example is the JQuery UI one, yours appears to be a different one.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is to set the datepicker defaults

folows the code that I used

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    onSelect: function () {
        $(this).focus();
        $(this).nextAll('input, button, textarea, a').filter(':first').focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
              onSelect: function(value, date) { 
                 window.location = 'day.jsp' ; 
              } 
        });
    });
 </script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

I think you can try this .It works fine .

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the datepicker from jqueryui.com/download and I got 1.7.2 version but still onSelect function didn't work.  Here is what i had -

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();

$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
      onSelect: function(value, date) { 
         alert('The chosen date is ' + value); 
      } 
});
```

I found the solution in this page -- [problem with jquery datepicker onselect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274347/problem-with-jquery-datepicker-onselect) . Removed the   $("#datepicker").datepicker(); once and it worked.

Comment: Howdy found the answer in another thread -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274347/problem-with-jquery-datepicker-onselect 

I was using datepicker event twice on a div. Should only be initialized once.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "datepicker", not "datePicker" if you are using the jQuery UI DatePicker plugin.  Perhaps, you have a [different but similar plugin](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/) that doesn't support the select handler.

Comment: Aha. Didn't knew there were different date picker plugins.
Whats the correct plugin to use then?

What I need is the "selectWeek: true" feature, and onSelect.