# problem with jquery datepicker onselect

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onselect

Following the basic onSelect spec on the jquery site I tried the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link type="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/latest/themes/base/ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.core.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryui.com/latest/ui/ui.datepicker.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();


$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert("Working"); }
});



  });

  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div type="text" id="datepicker"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And can't get it to work!
Originally been trying to get a more complicated thing to work but the onSelect was just not working so I went back to basics and still don't work, anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: Can you paste your html code where you create the datepicker?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might try removing the second `$("#datepicker").datepicker()` immediately above that line, leaving:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert("Working"); } });
});
```

Comment: Since this question was last answered the event names are different.  See here for events and examples: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html

Answer (score 45):

You're not using the api correctly.  Don't take it bad, it's confusing at first.

Both of these lines are telling the datepicker widget to initialize a datepicker on an element:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert("Working"); }
});
```

You could remove the first one since it's not doing anything except preventing the second one from having any effect.

If you want to change the value of one of the options after you've already initialized the widget then you would need to use this api:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

Or alternatively, you could attach a handler using jQuery's `bind` function:

```
$('#datepicker').bind('onSelect', function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

Comment: $("#datepicker").datepicker('destroy') and then setting up a new one with different options is another possibility - although in this case, just get rid of the first initialization.

Comment: BIG WIN! Your first answer of $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function() { /* do stuff */ }); did just the trick for me. Many thanks!

Comment: `$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function() { /* do stuff */ });` your answer worked for me thanks

Comment: check my question here- , I thought it was `drupal.behavior` issue but your trick seems to work for me http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133694/advagg-drupal-module-breaking-my-js-file... if you want you can add ans there -- @Ken Browning

Answer (score 33):

Must this code work when select a date:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
}).on("changeDate", function (e) {
    alert("Working");
});
```

Comment: Try all the variants and this was the only one which is working thanks @hamzeh

Comment: If anyone having a problem with methods that might because of you are using https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker so this is the way they are using

Comment: `"changeDate"` works for me too. `"option" "onSelect"` and other variants didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you..it saves my time."changeDate" only worked!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery datepicker's onSelect doesn't work sometimes but you can just bypass it by calling a method on `onchange` event of your `input` type.

```
function changeDate() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker(
        "change",
        { 
            alert("I am working!!");
        }
    );
}
```

Call this `changeDate()` method as-

```
<div type="text" id="datepicker" onchange ="javascript:changeDate();" />
```