# Using .change() and a datepicker in jquery to submit a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Currently I'm using JQuery UI's datepicker range, and I've added some more javascript that should submit the form on the page when different form elements change.

This works on the drop down I've added, as well as the date picker input boxes if I enter dates manually and then click away.

However, if I click an input field for the datepicker, and the date chooser pops up, the form will not submit after choosing a date..

Its as if the input field didn't know a change occured..?

http://api.jquery.com/change/

here is the code I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $('#from').change(function() {
                  document.myform.submit();
                });

            });
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#to').change(function() {
                  document.myform.submit();
                });

            });
```

Using the datepicker UI events, I've added the following code for testing but it isn't working.. any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $('#from').datepicker({
                   onClose: function() { alert('Yo yo!') }
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is here: [jQuery datepicker, onSelect won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887696/jquery-datepicker-onselect-wont-work)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI DatePicker has custom events, particularly the onSelect event, click the event's tab and it's at the bottom of the docs:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

Double check there are no JavaScript errors above the code you quoted.

If there are errors then the JavaScript code below these errors will not execute properly.

That is probably why the code you added to test did not work either.

Comment: Try using the onSelect event instead of the onClose event as @OriginalSyn suggested

Comment: I think the problem is that .change events are ["deferred until the element loses focus."](http://api.jquery.com/change/) This is why it only works when you specifically input the values. To get it to work when you select a date try use onSelect

Answer (score 0):

I hope it should be `on focus` . on click of date picker the focus will be in the text box where you have to show the date.
so the event should be `.focus()`

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

http://api.jquery.com/focusout/