# JavaScript code not executing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have some jQuery code that is not being executed. The code block looks like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#Start').datepicker();
$('#End').datepicker();
$('#End').val('date');
$('#Start').val('start');
alert('hello');
});
```

but its not applying datepicker on the `Start` and  `End` textboxes. Please note that jQuery and jQuery.ui files are added before this script. In this code block even the last line (`alert`) is not being executed.

I can see on error in Firefox console that reads `uncaught exception: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null` but it does not tell me the location of the error.

What could be the problem? why this code is not running? How to debug this?

**Edit 1:**
I have changed the code to following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        //$('#Start').datepicker();
        //$('#End').datepicker();
        //$('#End').val('date');
        //$('#Start').val('start');
        alert('hello inside');
    });
    alert("hello outside");
```

Now there are only two alerts (rest of lines commented) the alert outside ready function executes but one that is inside does not.

Comment: Based on the error, you probably have some other javascript code that is failing placed before this one.

Comment: have you looked in the javascript console to see if there is an error?

Comment: try using firebug's [https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/] console to see if it shows any error.

Comment: to debug, put alert('hello') to the top of the list and then see if it executes. if it does, then move it down step by step to see which function is causing the error. if it does not then most probably jquery library is not being properly included.

Comment: Are you using `canvas` — I've run into a similar error when I've had my `canvas` element set to `display:none` or `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: I am new to this project and haven't used canvas. can you tell me the js file names for canvas and I will search that in downloaded js list with the page

Comment: I am already using firebug and I have included the error details in my question. There is only one error without the location (line no column no etc)

Comment: Canvas is an HTML element `<canvas id="someID" width="200" height="100"></canvas>`. The element is usually accessed through `getElementById` It could be called anything...The variable `ctx` is a common way to set context. You could also do a search for `2d` or `3d`... Hope that helps

Comment: Are you sure jquery is being loaded correctly? If you take out all the datepicker code and *only* do an alert, does it get executed? Here's a fiddle with your code working correctly (at least for me) http://jsfiddle.net/N895K/2/

Comment: I am damn sure that jquery and jquery.ui are both loaded correctly. In script tab of firebug when I write an expression `$('#End').datepicker()`, it attaches datepicker to the element

Comment: Yeah, we have files like canvas.compiled.js and some others

Answer (score -1):

With the datepicker, i'm not sure you can set string value after initializing the datepicker.

Try removing those two lines :

```
$('#End').val('date');
$('#Start').val('start');
```

Comment: I did that after failing to attach the datepicker. it was just to check if code is executing and as a lost resort I inserted alert in the code but nothing executed.

Comment: Did you #end and #start element are <input type="text" /> node ?

Answer (score -1):

I never used Datepicker but I assume if you comment these lines out it will work:

```
$('#End').val('date');
$('#Start').val('start');
```

Most of jquery is asynchronous, ie. the two lines above will be executed before a date has been picked by the user (so values are missing). So you need to include a callback function like this (quick google)

[jQuery datepicker, onSelect won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887696/jquery-datepicker-onselect-wont-work)

```
    $('#End').datepicker( {
        onSelect: function(date) {
            alert(date);        }
    });
```

### Edit:

This works for me on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/q6UFc/):

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="end" name="end" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {          
$('#end').datepicker( {
            onSelect: function(date) {
                alert(date);        }
        });

})
```

Comment: This works for me on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q6UFc/ If it doesn't work I'll assume adaneo was right and some other javascript code is failing before this. Edit: Can you show us an example?